# Limits on Twitter E-Mail Notifications

Tags: notifications, twitter

What limits does twitter use for E-Mail Notifications (e.g., new followers, DMs, etc.)?

They seem to limit them. Some days I saw a stop of new mails after 50 messages on others it where like 113 in 24 hours, which seems an rather odd number. The exact amount doesn't seem to have a fixed 24 hour or per-day limit, but they stop unexpectedly.

On one account I would like to have notifications for all events, even when they are a lot, so I am interested in the limits and if there is a way to tune them (on the notifications tab on the web page there are no related settings for limiting the number of mails).